# Как отредактировать часть кода, чтобы айди пользователя удалялось из текстового файла?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, txt

Проблема состоит в том, что моя функция рассылки не работает из-за того, что в текстовом файле содержится айди-пользователя, который заблокировал моего бота. В цикле бот видит этот айди, пытается ему отправить сообщение, у него не получается, и консоле вылетает ошибка. Причем те, кто идет первыми в списке, получают рассылку, но после заблокированного пользователя, цикл прерывается.

“A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user” using telebot

я думаю, что достаточно будет просто удалять айди пользователя из файлика, чтобы цикл продолжался. просто я не знаю, как правильно это сделать.

```
joinedFile = open('D:/бот/joined.txt','r')
joinedUsers = set()
for line in joinedFile:
  joinedUsers.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start','Меню'])
def start(message):
  
  if not str(message.from_user.id) in joinedUsers:
    joinedFile = open('D:/бот/joined.txt','a')
    joinedFile.write(str(message.from_user.id)+'\n')
    joinedUsers.add(message.from_user.id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['secretword'])
def mess(message):

  try:
    for user in joinedUsers:
      bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])

  except telebot.apihelper.ApiException as e:
    if e.result.status_code == 403 or e.result.status_code == 400:
                    pass
```

Comment: обработать ошибку, вылетающую в консоли и пойти дальше??

Comment: успешная обработка ошибки является выполненная для всех пользователей, которые добавили к себе бота, функция рассылки

Comment: обрабатываешь ошибку try, в исключении удаляешь id из файлика и дальше идешь